# Where to get Context from standalone native application?

Tags: android, native

A standalone native application should perform calls to Java VM. Creating VM and playing with classes seem to be OK, but there is a problem while obtaining instance of Context. I can not create Application object and use it (NullPointerException is thrown). Also, Context class is abstract and can not be instantiated.
So, where can I get the Context object?.
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Activity extends Context, so your Activity IS a Context.

Comment: I have standalone **native** app written in C++, which does not have any Activity or another Android's stuff.

Comment: So, is any way to make Android create Context for my app? Actually, I need only Application object to get system services objects like NotificationManager or another system objects.